# Hide jquery validator messages for hidden fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want to hide jquery validation messages for hidden fields .

I have used jquery validator to validate hidden field using custom validator method.
Issue I am facing is when we input correct value in field error message is not getting removed.

Fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1r21359a/)

***CODE **

```
     $('#frm_managedeal').validate({
     ignore:[],
     invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {

        if (!validator.numberOfInvalids())
            return;

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(validator.errorList[0].element).offset().top
        }, 1);

    },
     rules:{

         dealExpirationDate:{
            mindatetoday :true,
         }

     },
     messages:{

         dealExpirationDate:{
            mindatetoday:'Expiration date should be greater than today'
         }
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your code:

```
/*added for validate*/
$('#frm_managedeal input').on('change', function() {
    $(this).valid();
});
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g7fkzu8r/)

Answer (score 0):

By default the validator only runs when the form is submitted. You could use a change event to validate fields whenever they change.

i.e.

```
$('#frm_managedeal').find('input, select, textarea').on('change', function() {
    (this).valid();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do it but this should be pretty easy. First I move your current validation process into a function that you can call like

```
    var validate = function (){
      //... code goes here ....
    }
```

then in your onclose: just call that function. Should be pretty straight forward